# Bounds on conditional expectations in GLMMs

Tags: mixed-model, references, glmm, conditional-expectation

Suppose $Y$ has the Bernoulli distribution and that $U$ is standard normal. Suppose also that

$$E(Y\mid U) = 1/(1 + e^{-\theta_1 - \theta_2 U}).$$

Can anything be said about the conditional mean of $U$ given $Y$? In particular, I'm interested in bounding $\vert E(U\mid Y) \vert$ with a function of $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, and $Y$.

In the language of GLMMs, I'm interested in the conditional expectation of the random effects given the responses, but I've tried to simplify the model here as much as possible. References to literature considering this, in any GLMM, is also of interest.